# download django 1.10 to python 3.5

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

How do I download django for python 3.5? When I run my virtual environment and type:

```
pip install Django
```

I get:

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): django in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

I noticed the problem when using PyCharm. PyCharm shows Django installed in Python 2.7, but not in 3.5. How do I pip install django into 3.5?

My main python package is 2.7. My work uses 2.7, and is migrating towards 3.5. So I'll need both, and would like to keep 2.7 as the default.

Comment: Make sure you activate the env before you pip install: `source bin/activate && pip install Django` OR specify the path to the right pip: `bin/pip install Django` and after that the right Python: `bin/python ...`

Comment: I have a virtual env activated rn. Django 1.10 is on it, but it shows on terminal and pycharm only on 2.7. i figure I need to make it go on 3.5 specifically. not sure how though.

Comment: You should specify which operating system you are running and ifyou have installed Python 3.5 or not.

Comment: This is not a Django OR virtual environment issue. It is about your PyCharm project not using the right environment. It uses your system Python. You need to configure PyCharm project to use your virtual env.

Comment: This is about which version of pip is being used to install Django, see my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using:

pip3 install Django or even pip3.5 install Django

This is what I used, as pip alone picks up python2 pip.  I have Django installed for both python2 and python3.

Answer (score 1):

You created your virtualenv with Python 2.7. You should first create a virtualenv with Python 3.5

```
virtualenv -p <path/to/python3.5> <path/to/new/virtualenv>
```

Then activate this new virtualenv, and finally, run `pip install django` on the virtualenv with Python 3.5

You can have as many virtual environments as you wish, but each virtualenv can only hold a single Python installation; if you don't specify a Python interpreter, the default one will be used to create the virtualenv (in your case, the default is 2.7)

Comment: when I made my virtual environment I typed: 'pyvenv-3.5 ./Env', then 'source ./Env/bin/activate', and finally 'pip install django'. when I type: 'python -m django --version' I get: '1.10'. However, my PyCharm doesnt show the django module in 3.5, only in 2.7. when I download it on their platform, it shows it being successfully downloaded, but still not working. It shows up as working when i change the interpreter to 2.7. but doesnt even show up in 3.5..

Comment: There is no need to re-install django through PyCharm, you just have to edit the interpreter to point to the one installed on your Python 3.5's venv. That's in Settings -> Project Interpreter -> Project Interpreter (add an existing one and simply point it to the right folder/path). If this was your issue let me know so I can edit the answer to reflect this new information

Answer (score 0):

the easiest to install any version of Django and python(linux) is by installing virtualenvwrapper for python:
here we go, first open your console
and type following command:
       1- sudo pip install virtualenvwrapper
       2-→ which virtualenvwrapper.sh
/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh(in my case)

```
   3-which virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
```

/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh

After this I had to configure a couple of things. First of all I have created a directory for the Python Virtual Environments:
mkdir ~/.virtualenvs

have also added an environment variable to my shell.  I use bashshell,then
If you are using a standard shell, like bash, you need to add the configuration to your ~/.bashrc file.

export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
I also had to add a command to the ~/.bashrc to run the activation script when my shell starts:
--> source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh
Finally to create a new virtual environment, for example if you want to create mytest virtualenvironment ,you just need to type this command from the terminal:

mkvirtualenv mytest

and that's all